# White spaces in an atomic_list_concat/3

Tags: prolog

I have this atom for example:

```
"The pen 
 is on
 the table"
```

If i use `atomic_list_concat(L, ' ', S)`, i obtain:

```
 L =[The, pen
     , is, on
     , the, Table]
```

and not:

```
 L =[The, pen, is, on, the, Table]
```

Why? How can I do to obtain the second solution?

EDIT: is it possibile to use two separator in `atomic_list_concat(L, Separator, S)` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cause of weird output is because there are newlines in text. And also multiple spaces would cause funny results.

You could add a a 'cleanup' procedure. I'm sorry it's complicated by the necessity to switch between atom/codes representations:

```
cleanup(Dirty, Clean) :- maplist(only_graphs, Dirty, Clean).

only_graphs(Word, Clean) :-
    atom_codes(Word, X),
    include(keep_graph, X, Y),
    atom_codes(Clean, Y).

keep_graph(C) :- code_type(C, graph).
```

*edit*: depending on your SW organization, you could *redefine* atomic_list_concat/3, but that would make the code base brittle.

I would advice to use instead something descriptive, like

```
separe_words(Atom, Words) :-
  atomic_list_concat(Dirty, ' ', Atom),
  maplist(only_graphs, Dirty, Words).
```

and add to your ~/.plrc, or your library

*edit* as you found out, there is normalize_space/2, that does better work.
Usage should be

```
separe_words(Atom, Words) :-
      normalize_space(atom(Clean), Atom),
      atomic_list_concat(Words, ' ', Clean).
```

Comment: In my system i used atomic_list_concat(Out, Separator, In), is it possibile to use two Separator instead only one? For example [' ','\n']

Comment: no, that would not make sense. After all, it's a concatenation. What should the system select among multiple separators ? If you need more flexibility, go with DCG.

Comment: And normalize_space/2? I found this predicate in library(xpath).

Comment: normalize_space/2 is in SWI_PROLOG, i don't use it. Where i found the source code of normalize_space/2? In YAP it isn't defined.

Comment: sorry, it's builtin (source is in C). The simpler route then should be the former separe_words/2

Comment: In fact, i don't found it in a library. I try separate_words/2, but it is equal to atomic_list_concat and I have always my first result. I tried to substitute  ' ' with '\n', but i obtain [The pen, is on, the table]

Comment: my former only_graphs/2 should work. Do you mean code_type(C, graph) is different between SWI and YAP ? That could be a bug worth a report.

Comment: I have a question. Where is defined only_graphs/2 ? Is it defined in the first code or it is builtin? Because i don't found it in the manual and I don't insert only_graphs(Word, Clean):- .... in my code.

Comment: it's in the answer. In manual you'll find code_type/2, that does all the dirty work

Comment: AFAIK, it's only in my code... The problem could be that, in YAP, differently than SWI, you need to *reconsult* sources to get an up-to-date program. Maybe it remembers a previous definition...